# Does no unstable manifold imply Lyapunov stability?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and suppose $0$ is a fixed point of $f$ (that is, $f(0) = 0$).
Does $W^u(0) = \varnothing$ imply that $0$ is a Lyapunov stable fixed point of $f$?
My guess is yes, but how can it be proved?
If not, what is a counterexample?
This seems rather fundamental, but I cannot find a solution online.

Definitions: the unstable manifold of $0$, denoted $W^u(0)$, is the set of all $x \ne 0$ for which there exists a backwards orbit with $f^i(x) \to 0$ as $i \to -\infty$.
The fixed point $0$ is said to be Lyapunov stable if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ there exists a (smaller) neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ such that $f^i(x) \in U$ for every $x \in V$ and every $i \ge 0$.

Comment: Let's imagine a system with a stable manifold $W^s(0)$ and a center manifold $W^c(0)$ through $0$. Let $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ be an $\epsilon$-ball around $0$. Is there necessarily a $\delta$-ball $B_{\delta}(0)$ such that the points in $W^c(0)\cap B_{\delta}(0)$ stay within $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ for all $t \geq 0$?

Comment: It depends on the dynamics on $W^c(0)$.  $W^c(0)$ can contain parts of $W^s(0)$ and $W^u(0)$.

Comment: This all depends on how you define $W^s$ and $W^u$. If you define them only as manifolds which are tangent to $E^s$ and $E^u$ respectively, then @MichaelLee gave an answer already. However, this requires $f$ to be at least $C^1$ or so. And there is another definition, which is written in your post, based purely on which trajectories converge to point in forward/backward time.

Comment: Yes I mean $W^s(0)$ and $W^u(0)$ to be points that converge to $0$ under forwards and backwards iteration, respectively.  If $f$ is differentiable and $0$ is hyperbolic, then $W^s(0)$ and $W^u(0)$ are tangent to $E^s(0)$ and $E^u(0)$, respectively.

Comment: It's not necessary for $0$ to be hyperbolic, it's enough to be differentiable. If it's differentiable, then you have no $W^u$, but definitely have either $W^s$ or $W^c$ (or both). And if you have $W^c$, as @MichaelLee said, you can make point Lyapunov unstable -- it won't violate having no $W^u$.

Comment: In the differentiable case I don't see how $0$ could be Lyapunov unstable due to the presence of a center manifold $W^c(0)$ that doesn't involve an unstable manifold $W^u(0)$.  But in any case, I'm most interested in scenarios where $f$ is non-differentiable, at least at $x=0$, and so the centre manifold theorem doesn't apply.